# How to align widgets in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to use PyQt5 for one of my GUI application. I could be able to add widgets as I want, but couldn't align them properly. I want to align my widgets as below:

[image]

But, My code is working something like this,

[image]

Following is my code, can anyone help me please?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDesktopWidget, QLabel


class GroupBox(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 900, 700))
        self.setWindowTitle("InvoiceMee - Split Documents")
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        groupbox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Files to Convert", checkable=False)
        layout.addWidget(groupbox)

        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        groupbox.setLayout(hbox)
        label = QLabel()
        pixmap = QPixmap('images.jpg')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        label.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
        pathBox = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        pathBox.setPlaceholderText("Enter the Path Here")
        pathBox.setGeometry(QRect(160, 150, 201, 20))
        selectFileBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Select")
        convertButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Convert")
        good_radiobutton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Invoices")
        naive_radiobutton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Credit Notes")
        hbox.addWidget(pathBox, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        hbox.addWidget(selectFileBtn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        hbox.addWidget(convertButton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        hbox.addWidget(good_radiobutton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        hbox.addWidget(naive_radiobutton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        hbox.addWidget(label,alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        hbox.addStretch()
        self.center()


    def center(self):
        # geometry of the main window
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        # center point of screen
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        # move rectangle's center point to screen's center point
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        # top left of rectangle becomes top left of window centering it
        self.move(qr.topLeft())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a QHBoxLayout (which stands for *horizontal* box layout). This means that all widgets that you added will be always displayed side by side, horizontally, according to the *order of insertion*.

You should use a layout that allows vertical orientation, instead.

You're using more than a widget per row, so you could use a QGridLayout, but, since some of those widgets have different horizontal sizes, the result might not be what you showed us.
The solution is to use nested layouts, with a main grid layout with stretch sets for first/third row and column and a "central" layout added to the second row/column of the grid. Then, whenever you need more than one widget in a row, add a nested QHBoxLayout.

```
class GroupBox(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 900, 700))
        self.setWindowTitle("InvoiceMee - Split Documents")
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        groupbox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Files to Convert", checkable=False)
        layout.addWidget(groupbox)

        # the "main" layout, used to ensure that the actual layout containing
        # all widgets stays in the center
        groupLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        groupbox.setLayout(groupLayout)
        groupLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        groupLayout.setColumnStretch(2, 1)
        groupLayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        groupLayout.setRowStretch(2, 1)

        # this is the actual layout used to add widgets
        centerLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        groupLayout.addLayout(centerLayout, 1, 1)

        label = QLabel()
        pixmap = QPixmap('images.jpg')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        # this won't work
        # label.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
        pathBox = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        pathBox.setPlaceholderText("Enter the Path Here")
        # this won't work either, the layout will try to move and resize it anyway
        # pathBox.setGeometry(QRect(160, 150, 201, 20))
        # use minimum width instead
        pathBox.setMinimumWidth(200)
        selectFileBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Select")
        convertButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Convert")
        good_radiobutton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Invoices")
        naive_radiobutton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Credit Notes")

        centerLayout.addWidget(label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        # the second row has more than one widget, use a nested horizontal layout
        inputLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        centerLayout.addLayout(inputLayout)
        inputLayout.addWidget(pathBox)
        inputLayout.addWidget(selectFileBtn)

        # the same for the radio buttons
        radioLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        centerLayout.addLayout(radioLayout)
        # use horizontal alignment to keep buttons closer, otherwise the layout
        # will try to expand them as much as possible (depending on the other
        # widgets in the centerLayout)
        radioLayout.addWidget(good_radiobutton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        radioLayout.addWidget(naive_radiobutton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)

        # use center alignment so that the button doesn't expand
        centerLayout.addWidget(convertButton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

I'd suggest you to carefully study how layout work and behave, make some experiments and also use Qt Designer to easily see how nested layout can work.

Also, consider that in some cases it might be necessary to set a specific size policy to avoid widgets expanding too much, and use a QWidget "container" can make things easier.
For example, instead of using the horizontal alignment when you add the radio buttons, you can use a QWidget container:

```
        # ...
        radioContainer = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        centerLayout.addWidget(radioContainer, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        radioContainer.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum,
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        radioLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(radioContainer)
        radioLayout.addWidget(good_radiobutton)
        radioLayout.addWidget(naive_radiobutton)
        # ...
```

Comment: Super...Thank you so much... Working Perfectly... Fine...

Answer (score 4):

Use `QGridLayout` instead of `QHBoxLayout`. Grid Layout gives you the option to layout your widgets in a grid like struture. Here's the official [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html) for `QGridLayout`.

You can change your layout like this:

```
grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
groupbox.setLayout(grid)
grid.addWidget(label,0,0,1,0,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
grid.addWidget(pathBox,1,0,QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
grid.addWidget(selectFileBtn,1,1,QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
grid.addWidget(good_radiobutton,2,0,QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
grid.addWidget(naive_radiobutton,2,1,QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
grid.addWidget(convertButton,3,0,1,0,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

Add a vertical spacer item if you want to remove space between your widgets:

```
verticalSpacer = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20,  QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
grid.addItem(verticalSpacer, 6, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
```

Comment: It worked! thank you. But, the grid is sitting on the top. How can I keep entire grid in center of the groupBox?

Comment: You can either add another `QSpacerItem`  as the first widget in the grid or use `setContentsMargin` property of the `QGridlayout`